# fastest way to write JSONOBJECT to file java

Tags: java, performance, json

I have a big JSONOBJECT in java and need to write it to a .gz file. I do it like this :

```
FileOutputStream output = null;
output = new FileOutputStream("filename.gz");
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(output), "UTF-8");
String jsonString = myjson.toString();
writer.write(jsonString);
```

the time that takes to run above code, is about 900 milliseconds. but when I've calculate the time of `String jsonString = myjson.toString();` I see that it takes about 800 milliseconds! is there a way to remove time of converting JSONOBJECT to string?

Comment: Use JsonWriter.

Comment: please give me a sample code

Comment: How you are preparing the `JSON object` ?